# Ag grid does not render properly (Angular 2 - webpack2)

Tags: asp.net, angular, npm, webpack, ag-grid

I'm currently trying to inject ag-grid in my angular2 project and I'm having an issue rendering it.

I'm trying to use this [ag-grid package](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-webpack-2/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) and to follow the tutorial with a .net projet generated with the command '**dotnet new angular**'.

Here is my agGrid.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GridOptions } from "ag-grid/main";

@Component({
    selector: 'ag-grid-component',
    templateUrl: './agGrid.component.html'
})
export class AgGridComponent {

    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    public rowData: any[];
    private columnDefs: any[];

    constructor() {

        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.createRowData();
        this.createColumnDefs();
        this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = {
            headerComponentParams: {
                menuIcon: 'fa-bars'
            }
        }

    }

    private createRowData() {
        this.rowData = [
            { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
            { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
            { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
        ];
    }

    private createColumnDefs() {
        this.columnDefs = [
            { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
            { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
            { headerName: "Price", field: "price" }
        ];
    }

}
```

And my agGrid.component.html :

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width:500px;height:200px" class="ag-fresh"
                    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                    [rowData]="rowData">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

I carefully imported AgGridModule from "ag-grid-angular/main", but the result is quite awful :

[image]

Can someone enlighten me please ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you aren't getting the css files, are those being imported somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

New to Angular 2/4 and Visual Studio 2017, but had the same issue.  Reading the two answers above helped tremendously.

I did the following to get the same sample in the original question working

1. Copied the CSS files from MyApp/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles to a folder under MyApp/wwwroot ( MyApp/wwwroot/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles ).  **Note**: copy only the CSS files.
2. Edit your Index.cshtml file to include the the two "link" tags.

   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
   }
   @*Loading...*@
   Loading...

   @section scripts {

   ```
   <link href="node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
   <link href="node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet" />


   <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
   ```

   }

Would like feedback on a more elegant solution...thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of a CSS styles loading, make sure you have imported the CSS files properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below lines to your main html file header.(start with < symbol)

link href="/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   link href="/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet"/>